# Clobber X,Y,Z Registers with avr-gcc

Tags: gcc, avr, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

If I code

```
    asm volatile("" ::: "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8",
                    "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15", "r16", "r17",
                    "r18", "r19", "r20", "r21", "r22", "r23", "r24", "r25",
                    "r26", "r27", "r28", "r29", "r30", "r31", "memory");
```

and dissassemble the result of avr-gcc I can see that avr-gcc assumes that X, Y and Z are not clobbered. However they are implicitly declared as clobbered as these are the pairs (r26, r27), (r28, r29) and (r30, r31). avr-gcc seems to treat X, Y, Z like separate registers.

If I try to fix this like so

```
    asm volatile("" ::: "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", "r8",
                    "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15", "r16", "r17",
                    "r18", "r19", "r20", "r21", "r22", "r23", "r24", "r25",
                    "r26", "r27", "r28", "r29", "r30", "r31", "X", "Y", "Z", "memory");
```

Then avr-gcc complains

```
test.cpp:212:91: error: unknown register name ‘Z’ in ‘asm’
test.cpp:212:91: error: unknown register name ‘Y’ in ‘asm’
test.cpp:212:91: error: unknown register name ‘X’ in ‘asm’
```

According to the compiler error as well as according to the documentation of the [Register Layout](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Register_Layout) it appears as if X, Y and Z can not be specified.

How can I then tell avr-gcc that all registers but "r0" are clobbered? In particular how do I tell it that X,Y,Z are clobbered?

Comment: I can't try this, but how about something like this: `asm volatile ("" : "=x" (junk1), "=y" (junk2), "=z" (junk3) ...`?

Comment: This might work. But unlike the clobber it would explicitly call to generate some machine instructions. This is what I want to avoid. If I find no better solution I will replace the whole block around the asm volatile with hand coded assembler. Its only two instructions anyway. So in this specific case the cheapest solution. However I still wonder how I might explicitily clobber x,y and z.

Comment: `it would explicitly call to generate some machine instructions` It would?  Like what?  Other than letting gcc know that on exit from the asm that the specified registers would be associated with the specified variables, I can't see what instructions would get generated.

Comment: So it /should/ work.  But I can't try it to see if it actually does.  Sometimes compilers surprise you.

Comment: On a note, at least inside a function I have not been able to clobber *all* registers. `Y` (`r28:r29`) is used as the frame pointer by GCC and it complains when it is left no more registers to store this pointer.